# Matplotlib transparent fill over an image

Tags: python, image, matplotlib

I am trying to draw a transparent polygon over an image on a canvas using matplotlib:

Code from canvas class:

```
def update_figure(self, dataOverride = None):
    if self.data is not None or dataOverride is not none:
        FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)
        self.axes.clear()
        if dataOverride is not None:
            self.axes.imshow(dataOverride, cmap = self.getColorMap())
        else:
            self.axes.imshow(self.data, cmap = self.getColorMap())
    self.draw()
```

Code I am having trouble with:

```
def renderPoly(self, pointListX, pointListY):

    #Adds in picture to self.ui.canvas2.axes
    self.ui.canvas2.update_figure()

    #Code that draws polygon with len(pointListX) points
    #with the points at pointListX and pointListY over the
    #current image in self.ui.canvas2.update_figure()
```

So, I want to replace the comments with something that will put a semi-transparent polygon OVER the imshow()'ed picture in self.ui.canvas2.axes.

Any suggestions??

Thanks,

tylerthemiler

Comment: one usually does not write 'Thanks, Tylerthemiler' in their questions here, this is a bit different than a forum. The idea is these questions should stand the test of time, be the same as someone else's down the road.

Comment: Your question is nicely laid out, giving some idea about what your trying to do, and where you are having an issue. But you haven't explained what you've tried so far. What kind of errors do you get? What polygon example have you tried? If you haven't tried an example, and can't find one with a simple (google) search, then tell us that: I can't find any good examples of adding a polygon to an axes. That will help the answer-ers to realize that you don't even have an example to work with.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't completely understand your code (please provide a fully working example), but the following code puts a polygon over an imshow image:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon

data = np.random.rand(4, 4)
plt.imshow(data)

pointListX = (0, 2, 1)
pointListY = (0, 1, 3)
xyList = list(zip(pointListX, pointListY))  # `list` not necessary for python2
p = Polygon(xyList, alpha=0.2)
plt.gca().add_artist(p)

plt.show()
```

If you have trouble with the stacking of objects, you can also explicitly set the `zorder` parameter.

Comment: I think it would be key to add that the `Polygon` units must be in data units, i.e. your random data goes from 0 to 3 on each axis, so that this the range of values for the polygon.

Comment: Also in this specific problem, `zip` would be used to make the Nx2 array out needed by the polygon out of the `pointListX` and `pointListY` arrays.

Comment: `zip` doesn't work in python 3. Probably because it returns an iterator, instead of the list it outputted in python 2.